# Dialogflow, setting two parameters from a single input

Tags: dialogflow-es

What I would like to do is set two parameters from one input. So as an example:

```
User1 says: I am flying to Madrid
User2 says: I am flying to MAD
```

For both messages I want to set two internal parameters:

- city-name=Madrid
- city-code=MAD

So I can have an entity like; reference value=MAD synonyms = Madrid – this gives me city-code=MAD alternatively I could do the opposite to get the name

Is there a way to get both city-name and city-code populated for both user messages?

I tried the below (image) as logically that should work but didn't.
[Intent config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhJ3L.jpg)

Thanks for any helps/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Entity types don't work this way. So the system won't automatically populate both.

However, you can create sample phrases that use one or the other and use fulfillment to determine the value of the "missing" parameter based on the value of the parameter that was provided. You can then make sure both are saved in a context for future use.